# How to add Progress bar to File Copy in Java

Tags: java

so I have class that is used to copy all of a specific file type from one directory to another directory.  This class does work, but I am curious on what would be the best method of adding a progress bar to let the users know how far along in copying all the files.
So my question is, what would be the best method of adding a progress bar to this class.  As you may see, there is no GUI being made by this class as it stands.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;



public class CopyFilesFromType
{
    public static void main(File SourcePath, File DestPath)
    {
        new CopyFilesFromType().copy("tif", SourcePath.toString(),        DestPath.toString());
    }

    private FileTypeOrFolderFilter filter = null;


    private void copy(final String fileType, String fromPath, String outputPath)
    {
        filter = new FileTypeOrFolderFilter(fileType);
        File currentFolder = new File(fromPath);
        File outputFolder = new File(outputPath);
        scanFolder(fileType, currentFolder, outputFolder);
    }

    private void scanFolder(final String fileType, File currentFolder, File outputFolder)
    {
        System.out.println("Scanning folder [" + currentFolder + "]...");
        File[] files = currentFolder.listFiles(filter);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                scanFolder(fileType, file, outputFolder);
            } else {
                copy(file, outputFolder);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copy(File file, File outputFolder)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("\tCopying [" + file + "] to folder [" + outputFolder + "]...");
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFolder + File.separator + file.getName()));
            byte data[] = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(data);
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private final class FileTypeOrFolderFilter implements FileFilter
    {
        private final String fileType;

        private FileTypeOrFolderFilter(String fileType)
        {
            this.fileType = fileType;
        }

        public boolean accept(File pathname)
        {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith("." + fileType) || pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream.`

Comment: Thank you, this has set me on the right track to get this going...attempting to properly wrap it myself at the moment, which is proving to be tricky for a beginner like me, but I think I can figure it out.